# Why can't I ignore the right Meta key in Emacs 29.1 on MacOS?

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I'm using GNU Emacs for MacOSX 29.1 under macOS Ventura, & I need to enter accented letters (é, à, &c.). Following the manual, wiki, & several articles, I used

```lisp
(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta)
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
```

to be able to use my right Option key as a symbol key while keeping the left one for Meta in Emacs. However, it doesn't seem to work at all: `M-e` still sends at the end of a paragraph instead of entering the dead ´, & `M-<backtick>` (I use the Dvorak layout) opens the menu in minibuffer instead of entering a dead `, as if the previous lines had no effect. I tried using only the second, or calling aliases (following the `describe-variable` help), but nothing changes.

To push it even further: I tried evaluating these (& aliases) in a vanilla Emacs (using `emacs -q`), however even there it doesn't do anything…

Is there something I missed? (Homebrew says I already have the latest version installed, if that can help…)

I tried using Emacs Customize, & it didn't work either. Also, I noticed this config works in terminal Emacs, so the issue only happens in GUI Emacs.